# How to do a where condition on a split comma-separated value

Tags: sql-server

I want to do a where condition on the following table but I don't how to do a split and a test after I get the values from my `Period` colomn :

```
Code     Period
1        PER1
2        PER
3        ESN;PER_ESN;PER
4        PRN
5        PRN1;PRN2;PRN3;PRN4
```

AN example of the query is the following :

```
select code from Mytable where Period like 'PER_ESN'
```

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Changed to handle parameter
Disclaimer. Your table is not normalized and it will give bad performance:

```
DECLARE @param_period VARCHAR(200) = 'PER_ESN'
SET @param_period =';'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@param_period,'_','[_]'),'%', '[%]') + ';'

SELECT code 
FROM Mytable 
WHERE ';' + Period + ';' LIKE @param_period
```

The reason for replacing wildchars is to avoid different text to be accepted in it's place.

Comment: ++ for '[_]', otherwise that would have been the next question.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk concerning the 'PER_ESN' this was just an example, I need something generic because i have a parameter_period :

Comment: where period = @param_period

Comment: but why the first `REPLACE`? there is no `'%'` in the `param_period`

Comment: There may not be % in your test data currently, but maybe there will be later since it is a parameter. This is to make sure your code will work in future senarios.